# how to move a file after grep command when there is no return result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I wanna move a file after the grep command but as I execute my script, I noticed that there are no results coming back. regardless of that, I want to move the file/s to another directory.

this is what I've been doing:

```bash
for file in *.sup
do 
   grep -iq "$file" '' /desktop/list/varlogs.txt || mv "$file" /desktop/first;
done
```

but I am getting this error:

```
mv: 0653-401 Cannot rename first /desktop/first/first
```

suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: use `;` instead of `||`

Comment: Is the error message you posted accurate? I'd expect 3 things; a reason for the error; the word "to", like "cannot rename x TO y"; and finally, and possibly the reason for the error - I'd expect the filename to be "first.sup", not "first", as the contents of the `$file` variable should traverse all filenames with that suffix.

Comment: @Sundeep That would break the script, not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the two single quotes are for in between `..."$file" '' /desktop...`. With them there, grep is looking also for `$file` in a file called `''`, so grep will throw the `grep: : No such file or directory` error with that there.

Also pay attention to the behavior change of adding the `-q` or `--quiet` flags, as it affects the returned value of grep and will impact whether the command to the `||` is run or not (see `man grep` for more).

I can't make out exactly what you are trying to do, but you can add a couple statements to help figure out what is going on. You could run your script with `bash -x ./myscript.sh` to display everything that runs as it runs, or add `set -x` before and `set +x` after the for loop in the script to show what is happening.

I added some debugging to your script and changed th `||` to an `if/then` statement to expose what is happening. Try this and see if you can find where things are going awry.

```bash
echo -e "============\nBEFORE:\n============"
echo -e "\n## The files in current dir '$(pwd)' are: ##\n$(ls)"
echo -e "\n## The files in '/desktop/first' are: ##\n$(ls /desktop/first)"

echo -e "\n## Looking for '.sup' files in '$(pwd)' ##"

for file in *.sup; do
  echo -e "\n## == look for '${file}' in '/desktop/list/varlogs.txt' == ##"

  # let's change this to an if/else
  # the || means try the left command for success, or try the right one
  # grep -iq "$file" '' /desktop/list/varlogs.txt || mv -v "$file" /desktop/first

  # based on `man grep`:  EXIT STATUS
  #   Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected,
  #   1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.
  #   However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line
  #   is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

  # note that --ignore-case and --quiet are long versions of -i and -q/ -iq
  if grep --ignore-case --quiet "${file}" '' /desktop/list/varlogs.txt; then
    echo -e "\n'${file}' found in '/desktop/list/varlogs.txt'"
  else
    echo -e "\n'${file}' not found in '/desktop/list/varlogs.txt'"
    echo -e "\nmove '${file}' to '/desktop/first'"
    mv --verbose "${file}" /desktop/first
  fi
done

echo -e "\n============\nAFTER:\n============"
echo -e "\n## The files in current dir '$(pwd)' are: ##\n$(ls)"
echo -e "\n## The files in '/desktop/first' are: ##\n$(ls /desktop/first)"
```

- `||` means try the first command, and if it is not successful (i.e. does not return 0), then do the next command. In your case, it appears you are looking in `/desktop/list/varlogs.txt` to see if any `.sup` files in the current directory match any in the varlogs file and if not, then move them to the `/desktop/first/` directory. If matches were found, leave them in the current dir. (according to the logic you have currently)
- `mv --verbose` explain what is being done
- `echo -e` enables interpretation of backslash escapes
- `set -x` shows the commands that are being run/ debugging

Please respond and clarify if anything is different. I am trying to raise in the ranks to be more helpful so I would appreciate comments, and upvotes if this was helpful.

Comment: Probably avoid `echo -e` in favor of `printf`

Comment: I just want to move the file or files that ends with the file extension **.sup** if there are no results in the grep command.

Comment: That was sorta the assumption I was making. The code I provided should do that. Please upvote or mark as answer if it provides what you need, or let me know how it doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to avoid repeated scans of `/desktop/list/varlogs.txt`, and remove duplicats:

```
mv $(grep -o -f <<<$(ls -1 *.sup) /desktop/list/varlogs.txt|sort|uniq) /desktop/first
```

Suggesting to test step `1.` in explanation below to list the files to be moved.

#### Explanation

##### 1. `grep -o -f <<<$(ls -1 *.sup) /desktop/list/varlogs.txt| sort| uniq`

List all the files selected in `ls -1 *.sup` mentioned in `/desktop/list/varlogs.txt in a single scan`.

`-o` list only matched filenames.

`<<<$(ls -1 *.sup)` prepare a temporary redirected input file containing all the pattern match strings. From the output of `ls -1 *.sup`

`|sort|uniq` Than, sort the list and remove duplicates (we can move the file only once).

##### 2. `mv <files-list-output-from-step-1> /desktop/first`

Move all the files found in step 1 to directory `/desktop/first`